# Why doesn't the Spinner trigger onItemselected?

Tags: java, android, xml, spinner

I use this java code in order to code an Android RPN calculator. Now I'm in the stage where clicking on the spinner the number of decimals shown are set. Unfortunately the Toast function called onItemselected does not work which I think means that the function is not called. Any ideas why?

Thank you!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

TextView stackedit0;
LinkedList<Double> fifo = new LinkedList<Double>();
int stack = 0;
int initialized = -1;
double m;

private Spinner spinner;
private static final List<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();

public void create_string() {

    for (int i=0; i<=1047; i++){

        paths.add(String.valueOf(i));

    }
}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

    Toast.makeText(this, parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}


public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String>adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,paths);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    create_string();
...
}

<Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="52dp"
            android:layout_height="19dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:background="#66000000"
            android:text="AC"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"/>
```

Comment: isn't the @override is mising in onItemSelected ?

Comment: Thank you for the replay! It was indeed, I fixed this now but the Toast message still doesn't show up.

Answer (score 1):

As you are populating the list after the adapter initialization so you can call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

after populating the list i.e. after create_string() method or initialize the adapter after populating the list.